# Calculate current mobile connection speed in Android?

Tags: android, connectivity

I need the current mobile connectivity speed of an android device.  I know how to get the speed link of the wifi connection, but not the mobile connection.

```
myWifiInfo.getLinkSpeed());
```

Been reading up on the TrafficStats class, but don't know what to calculate with the information given.  For instance:

```
TrafficStats ts = new TrafficStats();
Log.i("trace", "getMobileRxBytes : " + ts.getMobileRxBytes());
Log.i("trace", "getMobileRxPacets : " + ts.getMobileRxPackets());
Log.i("trace", "getMobileTxBytes : " + ts.getMobileTxBytes());
Log.i("trace", "getMobileTxPackets : " + ts.getMobileTxPackets());

Log.i("trace", "getTotalRxBytes : " + ts.getTotalRxBytes());
Log.i("trace", "getTotalRxPackets : " + ts.getTotalRxPackets());
Log.i("trace", "getTotalTxBytes : " + ts.getTotalTxBytes());
Log.i("trace", "getTotalTxPackets : " + ts.getTotalTxPackets());
```

Rx refers to "receiving" and TX refers to "transferring".

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429605/how-to-get-link-speed-programmatically

Comment: Above post doesn't indicate what to do with the available bytes and packets to determine speed. I'm looking for this answer.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want. Have you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) for what these mean? They are just the total bytes through the mobile network interface, or through all network interfaces. I don't see how that helps you

Comment: I've read the docs... very little help there.  Going back to the link you provided, it sounds like you can calculate current speed based on the user's available network default.  Was hoping someone could shed light on that a bit more.  Also, I was going to add an additional comment to the question, but figured posting a new question was more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Note time before storing total received bytes, wait for 10 to 20 secs whatever you like then again note total received bytes. Now find the difference in bytes and divide it with the waited number of seconds. The result will be your speed in Bytes per second.