# Calculating Internet Speed in android

Tags: android

I am working with an App which contains web service things.

In that I need to know the status when the Internet speed is low. How to find the internet speed level in Android?

For example, Consider if I am using 2Mbps connection in my cell phone and when it slows to 50Kbps I need to notice that situation by making a Toast or Alert.

Thanks.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429605/how-to-get-link-speed-programmatically

Comment: So what did you find? I want to check internet speed and set image or video url accordingly for example if internet speed is between `50kbps - 150 kbps`  **link1** , `150kbps -  500kbps`  **link2** and  `>500kbps` **link3**. so How to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are connected to `WiFi` you can find the speed of the connection using [`WifiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) :

```
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManger.getConnectionInfo();
```

and then from the [`WifiInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed%28%29) you can get the current speed :

```
int speedMbps = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
```

If you are on 3G, I don't think there is a standard way of finding out, maybe you can assume automatically that 3G is slow.

Comment: Any way thank you, but still i am searching for internet speed not only in wifi as well as in 3G,2G.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it's not possible to get your Internet speed like this since it's determined by your ISP, not your WiFi adapter or router

Comment: There is no `android library` that provides the speed of the network. `wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed` provides the maximum speed of the network only which keeps on changing time to time.

Comment: if user's are connected using Mobile data than which method is used to find out Speed of internet connection, please let me know if any one find out correct solution???

Comment: I want to check internet speed and set image or video url accordingly for example if current internet speed is between `50kbps - 150 kbps`  **link1** , `150kbps -  500kbps`  **link2** and  `>500kbps` **link3**. so How to achieve that?

Comment: network link speed != internet speed

Answer (score 0):

This is specilally to detect internet connection speed by 
[facebook sdk](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class)

```
ConnectionQuality cq = ConnectionClassManager.getInstance().getCurrentBandwidthQuality();
```

Comment: It's Always returns UNKNOWN.

Comment: This Always returns unknown

Comment: it always returns null because there was no network sampling done before fetching the value from network bucket, for this to work you need to start the sampling and download a dummy image from a server and then stop sampling. After that, you can get values from network bucket.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for getting speed of your internet while connected to wifi.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
    this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
for (ScanResult scanResult : wifiList) {
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(scanResult.level, 5);
    String net=String.valueOf(level);
   // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,net,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

// Level of current connection.here rssi is the value of internet speed whose value
// can be -50,-60 and some others,you can find the speed values easily on internet.

int rssi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
String net=String.valueOf(rssi);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,net,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// -100 is the minimum speed value of your internet.
if(rssi < -100) {
    slowInternet=false;
}
```